# Why does this code produce incorrect output?

Tags: c

```
char nation[100];

printf("Enter Your Name : ");
gets(nation);

int size = strlen(nation);

printf("Output = %f\n", size);
```

I need to solve the question, please.

Comment: Whoever told you to use `gets`, ignore all of that advice and delete this code. Do a proper C course.

Comment: The format `%f` is for *floating point* values, not integers. Use `%d` or `%i` for integer values.

Comment: See [Why the `gets()` function is too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)  It has the dubious distinction of being the only function removed from Standard C — and you should pretend it does not exist.  If your teacher teaches you to use it, you should try to get a better teacher, or point them to the linked question.  The first Internet worm, from 1988, thrived because a program used `gets()`.

Comment: If your compiler is not complaining that `%f` is the wrong format for printing an `int`, you need to turn on more compiler warnings or get a better compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
char nation[100];

printf("Enter Your Name : ");
fgets(nation, sizeof(nation), stdin);  //gets is depreciated use fgets instead

size_t size = strlen(nation);    //strlen returns size_t not int

printf("Output = %zu\n", size);  //%f is to print floats
```

You need to tell `printf` what type you want to print:

```
%c  character
%d  decimal (integer) number (base 10)
%e  exponential floating-point number
%f  floating-point number
%i  integer (base 10)
%o  octal number (base 8)
%s  a string of characters
%u  unsigned decimal (integer) number
%x  number in hexadecimal (base 16)
%%  print a percent sign
```